# Unexpected Angular ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError in template-driven form

Tags: angular, angular-validation, angular-template-form, angular-binding

I have a very simple Angular Component as follow:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'test-view',
  template: `
    <div [ngStyle]="{ 'background-color': m.invalid ? 'red' : 'green'}">{{m.status}}</div>
    <input #m="ngModel" type="text" [ngModel]="val" required/>
  `
})
export class TestViewComponent {
  val = 'test';
}
```

This example is very similar to the official Angular documentation for template driven forms (https://angular.io/guide/forms#show-and-hide-validation-error-messages).

When I run it using Angular 14.2 in debugging mode, the following error is displayed:

> ERROR Error: NG0100: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'green'. Current value: 'red'. Find more at https://angular.io/errors/NG0100

If I remove the `required` attribute from the input field or I invert the order of the div and input tags, the exception disappears.

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

That's typical error for Angular development, it occurs when you try to change any initial value on initialization proceess. Secondary check (works only in development mode) works on `AfterViewInit` hook. Because of that you catch the error.

A simple solution here is to trigger change detection process in `AfterViewInit` hook. Like this:

```
ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.cdRef.detectChanges();
}
```

But you should know this error means you're doing something wrong with your data initialization. Better is to recheck your data and prevent change values within init hooks.